# lambdabot suggests join, but it doesn't work

Tags: haskell, join, monads, higher-order-functions, lambdabot

Here is a higher-order function that applies an argument to a given function twice:

```
dapp :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a
dapp = \f x -> f x x

ghci> dapp (*) 5
25
```

Can we make that shorter? Let's ask lambdabot:

```
lambdabot> @pl \f x -> f x x
join
```

Hooray! Let's try it out:

```
import Control.Monad (join)

dapp :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a
dapp = join
```

But it doesn't work :(

```
No instance for (Monad ((->) a))
  arising from a use of `join'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) a))
In the expression: join
In an equation for `dapp': dapp = join
```

Why does this happen? Am I importing the wrong `join`? I couldn't find another `join` on Hoogle.

Comment: Just import `Control.Monad.Instances` - I think that instance lives there.

Comment: @Thomas How would I selectively import only the `Monad ((->) r)` instance?

Comment: @FredOverflow you cannot selectively import instances. You can `import Control.Monad.Instances ()`, which will import all instances and nothing else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Until recently](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Instances.html), the `Functor` and `Monad` instances for `(->) r` were [orphan instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) in `Control.Monad.Instances`.

However, starting from `base-4.6.0.0` (GHC 7.6.1), these instances have been moved to the Prelude and the (now empty) `Control.Monad.Instances` [has been deprecated](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Instances.html).

So to use these instances, either import `Control.Monad.Instances` or upgrade your GHC.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Neither did I. For some reason this was not mentioned in the [GHC 7.6.1 release notes](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html#id9281219).